# Clear filters in TelerikGrid when using FilterMode.FilterMenu

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using TelerikGrid in application made with C# and Blazor.
I am using InCell editing mode and filter mode FilterMenu and function OnUpdate="@UpdateItem".
Example: Currently, when I choose one filter for showing one datetime, and change one cell from that list, after updating it dissapears from list because filter for datetime is set and I changed datetime.
I want to see updated row and to clear all filters, I want to set one filter (id from updated item) so I can see just updated row.

I tried to use @ref="grid" and to clear all filters, but didn't get on with it.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible snippet of your code and/or at https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/.